# Specify allowed subclasses in interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, syntax

Is there any way to specify the allowed subclasses for an interface?

Let's say I have this classes:

```
public interface IDoable // specify that only A or it's subclasses can implement IDoable
{
    void Do();
}

public class A : IDoable
{
    public void Do(){};
    public void Foo(){};
}

public class B : IDoable // implementing IDoable on something other than A or its sublcasses doesn't make any sense
{
    // public void Do();
}
```

So later I will be able to do this:

```
IDoable d = new A();
d.Do();
d.Foo(); // I'd like to be able to do this.
```

Does C# support this kind of feature?

Comment: Isn't this the same thing as putting all functionality for IDoable in public methods in A and referring to it or its descendants via type A?  What do you gain from the additional interface type?

Comment: There's no point, really.  All subclasses of A automatically implement any interface that A implements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *cast* `d` to `A` in order to be able to call `Foo` on it:

```
((A)d).Foo();
```

Note that if `d` is not `A`, this will throw an exception.

Other options are to test the type of `d` using [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) or [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt) operators.

This of course goes against the point of using an interface to begin with.

Comment: ah, I just figured since you can access Objects methods via an interface, you might be able to change the base of an interface by a bit :p

Comment: @ProgrammerAtWork - The type of `d` is `IDoable`, meaning you can only use `IDoable` methods/properties.

Comment: You can also use Objects (base class) methods :^)

Comment: @ProgrammerAtWork - Yes, since everything inherits from `Object`, it is by definition part of `IDoable`.

Comment: Yep, so you could say that everything that implements an interface has to extend object. I just wanted to know if it was possible to change the base of an interface, but apparently it's not possible :p

Comment: @ProgrammerAtWork - Can you please explain what you mean by "the base of an interface"?

Comment: When you implement an interface, you can conceptually think of an interface as if it extends an Object. So you get a little bit of multiple inheritance, but because everything extends from Object this is not a problem. The reason you think like this is because you can call Object methods on an interface alone.

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't. An interface represents a contract, and any class that has access to it can implement it.

You can of course restrict the access to it by making it `internal` (so only the same assembly can access it).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to specify the allowed subclasses for an interface?

No, any class can implement an interface as long as it's accessible to it. The whole point of an interface is to *hide* the concrete type/implementation from it's consumer so for me it doesn't make sense to couple it in the way your suggesting.